# All manifolds which satisfy the Pythagorean theorem are flat

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I was browsing through MathOverflow and read the following comment on this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/130898/119418):

> Here is a way to see that the (Pythagorean) theorem is not trivial ;-) : assume you have a complete Riemannian manifold such that any two distinct points are joined by a unique geodesic. Assume that any triple of distict points $x, y$ and $z$ such that the geodesics $xy$ and $yz$ form a right angle at $y$ satisfy $$d(x,y)^2+d(y,z)^2=d(x,z)^2$$ Prove the manifold is flat.

This seems really interesting and strong. I kept thinking about it for a while but I haven't been able to prove it. How would one go about proving this? I'd appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an outline.
Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$, a point $p \in M$, and a 2-dimensional subspace $V \subset T_p M$, and let $e : V \to M$ be the exponential map. Let $\kappa$ be the Gaussian curvature at $p$ of the surface $e(V)$.

Let $\triangle X O Z \subset V$ be a $45$-$45$-$90$ right triangle where $O$ is the origin; we will suppose this triangle is sufficiently small. Let $x=e(X)$ and $z=e(Z)$, and of course $p=e(O)$. We have a triangle $\triangle xpz$ whose legs $xp$, $pz$ meet at a right angle.

Show that if $\kappa > 0$ then the Pythagorean theorem fails in the manner of a sphere of curvature $\kappa$, and if $\kappa < 0$ then it fails in the manner of a hyperbolic plane of curvature $\kappa$.   There will be error terms, but the error term will be small in ratio to the diameter of $\triangle XOZ$.

Comment: You may want to mention the Hinge Comparison theorem here.

Comment: Don't know that theorem title.

Comment: Hah, it's simple enough.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but there's a couple things that still went pass me: where did you use completeness and the hypothesis that there is a unique geodesic joining the points?

Comment: That comment you linked is, like many comments on this site, is written in a kind of rough-and-ready manner. In this case those hypotheses you are concerned about are sufficient but not necessary for the property that you are asking about. A weaker sufficient condition is simply the existence of a unique geodesic between two points, which is true on any sufficiently small ball around any point. That condition is used in my answer to get the third side $xz$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see now.